# "This several minutes" vs "These several minutes"?

Tags: grammar

What is more suitable for the following context?

1. **This** *several minutes* **is** important for me"
2. **These** *several minutes* **are** important for me"

Comment: **This** is singular, **these** is plural, so **these** looks to fit better

Comment: If you want to use **this** you have to use it with a singular noun as in: **this** short, several-minute **window of opportunity** is important to me :-)

Comment: Though the way the example sentence is phrased (*This/These several minutes is/are*) makes it sound better to me to use *These* and *are*, let's not forget that an "amount" (of something) can be and usually is thought of as a singular noun. For example, here is a sentence from COCA: *It's what I call quiet time and that may be devotional reading, prayer, a bible reading. But I think that **30 minutes is very meaningful** in terms of how you start your day.*

Comment: To say it  plainly, "This several minutes is ..."  is horrible grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically correct would be *these several minutes are important for me* since *minutes* is a plural form.